# Compounding of functions based on brackets in Python

Tags: python, higher-order-functions

I have been given such a problem in school and I am cracking my head over it.

Let's say I have this function:

```
def twice(f):
    return lambda x: f(f(x))
```

Ok, what I think it does is to apply x to function f, then apply the result to f again. Fair enough.

I am then told to evaluate the following 2 statements:

```
print(twice(twice)(twice(lambda x: x+3))(2))
print(twice(twice)(twice)(lambda x: x+3)(2))
```

Forgive me if I am unable to provide any thought process, because I have been completely overwhelmed by these 2 after attempting to evaluate them. I know upon evaluation in Python that the first statement prints 26, and the second prints 50. I asked my professor for help, but all he told me was "Hint, note the opening and closing of parentheses". What I'm lost in is primarily how I can expand the "twice" functions given the brackets they are in.

In which case, what difference does it make between `(twice(lambda x: x+3))` and `(twice)(lambda x: x+3)`? Does anyone have any advice how I can trace this kind of quote?

Any help is greatly appreciated, and I thank you dearly in advance.

Comment: A hint: can you figure out what the function `twice(lambda x: x+3)` is? It helps if you give `lambda x: x+3` a name, like `a`. Now figure out what `twice(a)` is. Since `twice(a)` is itself a function, you'll want to apply it to something. The first question to answer thus becomes: what is `twice(a)(x)` for an arbitrary (say integer) `x`? (Answer: `twice(a)` is the function that adds 6 to its argument.)

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I guess I mostly understand the basics of where you're coming from, but I'm still not quite getting the difference caused by the parentheses. twice(twice(a)), as I understand, is twice(a(a)), which is a(a(a(a))) (or is it not?). Then what's the difference between that and (twice)(twice(a))?

Comment: @a9302c Your understanding of `twice` is wrong. It does not apply anything at all. It actually returns a function object, and it is *that* inner function that does all the work. However, the inner function won't do anything unless it is explicitly called after it is returned from `twice`. The best way to unpack all the calls is to remove the surrounding `print(...)` and then read from *right to left* to see what argument is being passed to which function (whilst remembering that `twice` always returns a function).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In which case, what difference does it make between `(twice(lambda x: x+3))` and `(twice)(lambda x: x+3)`?

Context. You're incorrectly taking them (or rather the latter) out of context. Without context, those two snippets mean the same thing, namely `twice(lambda x: x+3)` with pointless extra parentheses.

You're basically seeing `f(g(x))` and `f(g)(x)` and omit the `f` and ask for the difference between `(g(x))` and `(g)(x)`. That's wrong. In context, they mean `f(g(x))` and `(f(g))(x)`, respectively. Note the extra parentheses I added to the latter. The former computes `g(x)` and then applies `f` to it. The latter computes `f(g)` and then applies that to `x`. That `(g)(x)` never really existed.

Thus when thinking about `(twice)(lambda x: x+3)`, you're already lost. That's just not part of what's happening. The function actually written left of that is applied to `twice` first, and the resulting function is then applied to `lambda x: x+3`.

Using [function composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition) notation we can write twice(f)=f∘f and (f∘g)(h)=f(g(h)) and thus rewrite the functions to simpler forms.

The first one:

twice(twice)(twice(add3))
= (twice ∘ twice)(twice(add3))
= twice(twice(twice(add3)))

So twice twice twice, i.e., eight times, add3 gets applied.

The second one:

twice(twice)(twice)(add3)
= (twice ∘ twice)(twice)(add3)
= twice(twice(twice))(add3)
= twice(twice ∘ twice)(add3)
= ((twice ∘ twice) ∘ (twice ∘ twice))(add3)
= (twice ∘ twice ∘ twice ∘ twice)(add3)
= twice(twice(twice(twice(add3))))

So twice twice twice twice, i.e., 16 times, add3 gets applied.

Answer (score 1):

If you define the `twice` function to print out some logging and make the lambda explicit, it's easier to see the path:

```
def twice(f):
    def f2(x):
        res = f(f(x))
        print(f"{f.__name__}({f.__name__}({x})) = {res}")
        return res
    return f2

def add3(x):
    return x+3
```

Your first example is taking a function that adds `3` and creates a function that adds `6`. It then creates a function that runs it four times and applies it to the number `2`:

```
>>> twice(twice)(twice(add3))(2)
twice(twice(<function twice.<locals>.f2 at 0x7fa72f080310>)) = <function twice.<locals>.f2 at 0x7fa72f0804c0>
add3(add3(2)) = 8
add3(add3(8)) = 14
f2(f2(2)) = 14
add3(add3(14)) = 20
add3(add3(20)) = 26
f2(f2(14)) = 26
f2(f2(2)) = 26
26
```

Your second example is taking a function that runs a given function twice and creates a function that runs a given function four times. It then creates a function that runs a given function *sixteen* times, before applying that to a function that adds `3`, then applies that function to the number `2`:

```
>>> twice(twice)(twice)(add3)(2)
twice(twice(<function twice at 0x7fa72f080160>)) = <function twice.<locals>.f2 at 0x7fa72f080310>
twice(twice(<function add3 at 0x7fa72f0803a0>)) = <function twice.<locals>.f2 at 0x7fa72f080280>
twice(twice(<function twice.<locals>.f2 at 0x7fa72f080280>)) = <function twice.<locals>.f2 at 0x7fa72f0801f0>
f2(f2(<function add3 at 0x7fa72f0803a0>)) = <function twice.<locals>.f2 at 0x7fa72f0801f0>
add3(add3(2)) = 8
add3(add3(8)) = 14
f2(f2(2)) = 14
add3(add3(14)) = 20
add3(add3(20)) = 26
f2(f2(14)) = 26
f2(f2(2)) = 26
add3(add3(26)) = 32
add3(add3(32)) = 38
f2(f2(26)) = 38
add3(add3(38)) = 44
add3(add3(44)) = 50
f2(f2(38)) = 50
f2(f2(26)) = 50
f2(f2(2)) = 50
50
```

We can get a better idea of the order of evaluation by adding brackets and seeing that the result is the same:

```
>>>>( twice(twice)(twice) ) (add3)(2)
....
50
```

This hurt my brain somewhat.

Comment: Thank you so much for going through all this trouble to explain! More than I asked for, and quite clear! I will take some time to properly digest this. Greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: I was curious myself!